# How to solve error: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, database

this is my code

```
private String dbURL;
private String dbUsername = "root";
private String dbPassword = "root1234";
private String URL = "localhost";
private String port = "3306";
private String dbName = "university";
private Connection con;

private void connectToDataBase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + URL + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?verifyServerCertificate=false";
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("user", dbUsername);
    p.setProperty("password", dbPassword);
    p.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
    p.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, p);
```

and i encountered this problem
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huC2N.png)

Comment: The variable `private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";` have the structure jdbc:mysql.... bla bla and in your function have `dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + URL + ":"` if you print this, maybe say `jdbc:mysql://jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:3306...`
This is consistent with the error that's show `Malformed database URL,`.
I recommend you change the URL variable to `URL = "localhost"`

Comment: Can you show the entire class?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding up extra with your URL;
First you declared this:

```
private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
```

Now, in the connectToDatabase method you are building the dbURL by putting that URL in between:

```
dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + URL + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?verifyServerCertificate=false";
```

Your actual dbURL will practically look like: 
dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?verifyServerCertificate=false";

So, initialize URL just as:

```
 URL = "localhost";
```

Comment: thank you, but it sill gave me another error:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to help to resolve the problem with the provided details:).
Try,

```
dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + URL + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?verifyServerCertificate=false"+ "&useSSL=false";

Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("user", dbUsername);
p.setProperty("password", dbPassword);

Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, p);
```

Note: I didn't set `"autoReconnect", "true"`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. For me it occurred because I was using a very old mysql.connector jar version. Resolved it by upgrading `mysql.connector.java jar` from `mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.4.2` to `mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29`.
In IntelliJ, you can check the version of this jar by navigating to File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> `mysql.connector.java`